# GetMonthName: Valid values are between 1 and 13, inclusive. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimeformatinfo

I accidentally passed 0 into `DateTimeFormatInfo`'s `GetMonthName` method:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo info = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
var monthName = info.GetMonthName(0);
```

and got a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with this error message: **Valid values are between 1 and 13, inclusive.**

Passing in 1 through to 12 return "January" through to "December" but passing in 13 returns an empty string.

I can see why month numbers are not zero indexed, but what's month 13 for?

Comment: Purely a guess, however lunar calendars (e.g., Jewish) have a leap month inserted every so many years because of considerably shorter months.

Comment: Oh, and if it's Friday 13th on the 13th month, don't even switch your PC on.

Comment: @leppie Note that calendars and dates are a slippery slope, so your "interesting"... beware, here there be dragons :)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I tend to avoid any conversations containing the words 'posix time'  ;p

Comment: Clearly it's for the underappreciated month of Dodecember.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because calendar objects can accomodate 13 months (to handle calendars based on lunar months), see MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx

> Calendar objects can accommodate calendars with 13 months. For 12-month calendars, the empty string is always returned as the name of the 13th month.

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx)

> Calendar objects can accommodate
>   calendars with 13 months. For 12-month
>   calendars, the empty string is always
>   returned as the name of the 13th
>   month.

Answer (score -2):

I guess it is used to determine the leap day in the julian calendar ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar ). As most of use use Gregorian calender just do not worry.

Comment: -1: No, it ios for Lunar calendars that add an extra month form time to time to avoid drifting too far form the solar year.